# error CS1503 cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback' in blazor

Tags: html, asp.net-blazor

```
<div>
    <InputeFile class="form-control" @onchange="SelectBanner"></InputFile>
</div>
```

I want to get full path of file from input in blazor page 
but I have this error: 
**cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback' in blazor**

and this is my method that should get full path of selected file:

```
@code {
           protected string banner;

           protected async Task SelectBanner(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
           {
               banner = e.File.Name;
           }
      }
```

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong Event callback, it should be

OnChange

instead of

@onchange

so your code should look like this

```
<div>
    <InputFile class="form-control" OnChange="@(async e=>await SelectBanner(e))"></InputFile>
</div>

@code {
    protected string banner;

    protected async Task SelectBanner(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        banner = e.File.Name;
    }
}
```